# Quand je compile mon document tex, il m'affiche cet avertissement [When I compile my tex document, it shows me this warning]

Tags: hyperref

Package hyperref Warning : Token allowed in a PDF string
(PDFDocEncoding): 
(hyperref) removing 'math shift' on input line 26.

Comment: That's a warning not an error. Show a small complete example.

Comment: It is not an error. The warning happens in cases such as `\section{Text with $m+a+t+h$}` (a section title with math in it). You can use `\textorpdfstring` or ignore the warning.

Comment: Might be an idea to edit the title to english and something more related to the question

Comment: Welcome to TeX S.E. Please provide a MWE. Btw, si vous êtes plus à l’aise pour poser vos questions en français, vous pouvez le faire sur texnique.fr